# Build WatchKit App - Embedded Binary Validation Utility

Tags: xcode, watchkit

Currently i run into a problem that i can't understand, i created my profiles and try to run the build for iTunes Connect but i end with that error.
[image]
I Checked the Value and both are set the same as you can see here

[image]
and that one

[image]

they are the same.... anyone else a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your AirportWatch WatchKit app Bundle identifier become `de.fboulegue.AirportWatch.watchkitapp` and your error will disappear.